# Consuming a WCF REST Service in .NET?

Tags: wcf, rest, soap, sharepoint-2010, wcf-binding

I've this WCF service hosted in a Sharepoint 2010 web application. The WCF has been created using the following factory:

```
Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
```

As you can see this is creating a REST-type service. Because we needed to consume it client-side via jQuery.

Now we also need to access it from a .NET project (WinForms). I've tried adding the Service Reference in VS but it doesn't find anything. I guess that's because it's not a SOAP service right?

So how can I consume it in C# .NET project without breaking the existing jQuery support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Add Service Reference does not work for WCF REST services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx). You have a couple of options here:

1. Add another endpoint to your service, a SOAP-based one, so that you'll be able to use Add Service Reference on your client. I don't know exactly what the `MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory` does, but you could look how it creates its endpoint(s) and recreate that in another factory - and then add the additional SOAP endpoint
2. Another alternative is to share the interface definition (the service contract plus any existing data contracts) between the service implementation and the .NET client. Having that interface you can use the `WebChannelFactory<T>` to create a proxy to the REST service (like you'd have one for a SOAP service).

Comment: I'm not sure how to view what the factory creates. I went to the Sharepoint folder (ISAPI) where the .svc is deployed but there's no web.config there. So I don't really know where exactly is defining the endpoints.